# How to print an array in assembly?

Tags: assembly

Here is the function I wrote for reading a hex number:

```
readhex:
xor     ebx,ebx
.nextchar:
call    readchar    ;function to read a char and store it in al

;jumps to the end if Enter
cmp     al,13
je      .end
call    writechar    ;function to print a char from al
cmp     al,'A'
jb      .dec     ;it might be a number
cmp     al,'F'
ja      .error
inc     ebx    ;counts size of the array
jmp     .next   

.dec:
cmp     al,48
jb      .error
cmp     al,57
ja      .error
inc     ebx

.next:  
;stores the character
stosb
jmp     .nextchar

.error: 
call    writeln    ;function for linebreak 
mov     eax, errormessage
call    writestr    ;function to print a string on the screen
call    writeln
xor     ebx,ebx
jmp     .nextchar

.end:
ret
```

And here is the function to print this number:

```
printhex:

push    edx
push    esi
;prints the 0X prefix for a hex number
mov     eax, prefix    ;prefix is a string containing "0X"
call    writestr    ;function to print a string

mov     ecx,ebx
lodsb


.print:
call    writechar    ;function to print a char from al
cld
loop    .print

call    writeln
pop     esi
pop     edx
ret
```

And the main function:

```
;reads a hex number
mov     eax,readahexnumber    ;displays a message asking for a hex input
call    writeln
call    writestr
lea     di,[string]
call    readhex    ;function to read a hexadecimal number
call    writeln

;prints the hex number
lea     esi,[string]
call    printhex
call    writeln

ret
```

The program asks for a number, reads it and then displays the 0x prefix and the number, **but adds extra characters to the end of it**.  i.e. if input is AB1, the program will print 0xAB1AAA to the screen. Can anyone help me solve this, please?

Comment: Are you certain that `writestr` preserves `ebx`? Have you checked what the value of `ebx` is after `readhex` returns, and then again right before the `.print` loop?

Comment: One way to get discrepancy is to enter string like `ABx1` (the invalid `x` will reset count in `ebx`, but not `edi`, so the stored input will be `AB1` and returned count will be `1`). `lea     di,[string]` should be `lea     edi,[string]`. But otherwise it is not clear why it does not work, look OK to me, so you need to check in debugger, what is actually happening. .. oh.. the `.print` loop is actually wrong, finally I got it. will answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General answer is, that you **must** learn to use debugger, you must be capable to single-step over instructions, and check any register value, and any memory value, at any time, so you can validate/reason about your every assumption/expectation. From there it will be sort of simple to find problems like this, in debugger it will be quite obvious what is wrong with your code and why `AAA` is outputted.

Programming in assembly without debugger is like assembling robot blindfolded. You can do it, but it takes lot more effort (about 100x times more if you are talented, 1000+x or making you completely incapable to finish your task if you are not talented - and I'm not exaggerating this one, the 100x is quite conservative estimate from my experience, as I had to fix my code without debugger for years (and without computer, just with paper and pen), so I can compare).

Some notes... your functions are barely "readhex" and "printhex", more like "readstring_only0to9AtoF_valid" "writestring_with_hex_prefix". "read/write hex" sounds a bit more like there will be also conversion to/from binary value.

`lea     di,[string]` should be `lea     edi,[string]`, makes me a bit wonder, why the code works for you without that, you probably did set `edi` to some other valid address in `.data` before, so the upper 32 bits are already OK, or the assembler is silently fixing it into `edi`, or the address is value < 65536 (most unlikely), check disassembler in debugger if you got really `lea di`, and what value is in `edi` before the `lea`. So you **know** exact reason, why it works by accident for you, even with the bug (this bug may be actually hard to spot in debugger - as long as it works by accident - if you are not reasoning about every instruction deeply).

`printhex:` problem:

```
    mov     ecx,ebx
    lodsb
```

Loads first character of input, and adjusts `esi` - two problems:

1. this happens **outside of loop**, so you will output the same char inside loop (being lucky enough, that `writechar` does not modify `al`).
2. this is done before `cld`, so would you have `DF=1`, it would decrease `esi`, then inside the loop the `cld` is "late" switch to forward direction.

Actually your whole code looks to be designed as if it expects DF=0 all the time, so put single `cld` somewhere near the start of your code, and forget about it (unless you will add some function with `std`, then it should restore `cld` before exit).

```
.print:
    call    writechar    ;function to print a char from al
    cld
    loop    .print
```

[Why `loop` is slow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35742570/4271923) - rather use `dec ecx` `jnz .print`. But then you can use the `ebx` as counter, so you can remove also `mov ecx,ebx` and keep `ecx` intact, using `dec ebx + jnz` to loop.

And the `cld` is quite useless inside the loop. If you need it, it should be used before first `lodsb`.

Another problem I just **guess** because you didn't show your data definitions (which is sort of very bad in the question about assembly, data - values and structure - are often **more important than code**, so leaving them out is wrong, don't do that again).

```
mov     eax, prefix    ;prefix is a string containing "0X"
call    writestr    ;function to print a string
```

The `prefix` string is probably missing nul terminator, and the `string` buffer is defined right after it. So this `call writestr` will output whole `0XAB1` memory, before accidentally finding some zero to stop.

The remaining `AAA` output is from your character loop. Again a bug, which would be obvious from debugger, as after the `call writestr` to display prefix you would have on screen already whole number, not just expected "0X".

The `readhex:` has invalid handling of invalid characters, it will reset `ebx` counter, but not the input buffer pointer, so input like `ABx1` will set input buffer to `AB1`, but return only `1` in `ebx`.

I would probably re-arrange the whole check a bit:

```
readhex:
    mov     ebx,edi     ; remember start of input buffer
.nextchar:
    call    readchar    ;function to read a char and store it in al
    ;jumps to the end if Enter
    cmp     al,13
    je      .end
    call    writechar   ;function to print a char from al (echo input)
    ; check if input character is valid 0-9A-F
    cmp     al,'F'      ; 'F' is maximal valid value
    ja      .errorchar
    cmp     al,'0'      ; '0' is minimal valid value
    jb      .errorchar
    ; here '0' <= al <= 'F' - now just verify the range between
    cmp     al,'9'
    jbe     .validchar  ; AL is '0'..'9', accept it
    cmp     al,'A'
    jae     .validchar  ; AL is 'A'..'F', accept it
.errorchar:
    call    writeln     ;function for linebreak
    mov     eax, errormessage
    call    writestr    ;function to print a string on the screen
    call    writeln
    mov     edi,ebx     ; reset input buffer
    jmp     .nextchar

.validchar:
    ;stores the valid character
    stosb
    jmp     .nextchar

.end:
    ; calculate input length and return it in EBX
    sub     edi,ebx
    mov     ebx,edi
    ret
```

Comment: This helped a lot! The `prefix` was missing the null terminator, indeed, that's why it printed the string right away, and then entered the loop. Now I changed it to a jump condition, also fixed the reset of the ebx counter and other major bugs you pointed out.
I am new to Assembly, still trying to figure out how to use the debugger, but I will take the time to play with it.
Thank you for your time. :)